# Prove that $\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

A colection $\mathcal{V}$ of open sets in a topological space $X$ is called a **Fundamental System of Open Neighborhoods (FSON)** of a point $x\in X$ when:

1. $\forall\  V\in\mathcal{V}$ we have that $x\in V.$
2. If $A\subset X$ is open set containing $x$ then $\exists\ V\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $V\subset A$.

For example in any metric space the set $\{B(x,\frac{1}{n}); n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a **FSON** of $x$.

Let $\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R})$ the set of continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with a topology defined by the following way: Let $f\in\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R})$ and a continuous positive function $\varepsilon:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ and define the set $B(f,\varepsilon)=\{g\in\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R}); |g(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon(x)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ which is a basis for the topology.

> Prove that $\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable.

**Hint:** Show that $f=0$ doesn't have a countable **FSON**.

**Attempt:**

> Suppose that we have a countable **FSON** called $\mathcal{R}_{0}$ of $f=0$ then $\mathcal{R}_{0}=\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Then for each $A_i$ I can choose $\varepsilon_i$ such that $0\in B(0,\varepsilon_i)=\{g\in\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R}); |g(x)|<\varepsilon_i(x)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset A_i$. Then I need to find a positive function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $B(0,\varepsilon_i)\nsubseteq B(0,\varphi)$. If were $\varepsilon_i(x)=\frac{1}{n}\ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$ I have that $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the condition. But I don't know how to find $\varphi$ in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ choose a positive number $r_n<\epsilon_n(n)$. Now construct a continuous $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^+$ such that $\varphi(n)=r_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. (A piecewise linear function is continuous and easy to construct.) Then $B(0,\varphi)$ does what you want.

Comment: Wonderful construction. Thanks Brian!! was exactly what I needed

Comment: What topological property of $\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{R})$ allow us to construct this function?

Comment: @Gastón: I’m not sure what you mean. It’s really just the fact that there are positive real numbers arbitrarily close to $0$ that lets us construct $\varphi$.

Comment: Brian, this is the kind of very useful tricks for analysis. I know very few tricks like diagonal argument when we deal with a sequence of subsequences. Where can I find this kind of **useful** tricks (I'm not interesed in all tricks, only in fundamental tricks for learn analysis)

Comment: @Gastón: I honestly don’t know. These are things that I either learned so long ago that I’ve forgotten how I learned them or independently came up with for myself at some point. My best advice is just to keep an eye open for techniques that seem likely to be useful.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help Brian

Comment: @Gastón: You’re welcome; I’m sorry that I can’t offer anything more helpful.

Comment: your construction is very similar to cantor diagonal argument